# MySQL 5.1 service is utilizing 191 MB on startup with zero catalogs. Can I reduce this?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, memory, service

I'm configuring a new web-server.

I've noticed that mysql 5.1 (default installation) is taking up 191 MB without any catalogs configured. This is also without any programs logged into mysql and zero queries having been run on it.

This seems a bit excessive.

Any thoughts on how to reduce this amount without significantly effecting speed?

Thanks.

Edit: I just noticed in the Resource Monitor that Commit column lists 191 MB, while the Working Set column reads 33 MB. Private Column shows 28 MB. In the Task Manager Processes Tab, it only shows 28 MB. A big concern of mine is that the Physical Memory Usage in the Performance Tab of the Task Manager shows that the full 191 is beign used (It seems to be allocating the full "Commit Column" amount because 671/980 MB are being used when MySQL is the only major thing installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see your configuration, however a simple way to lower memory is to disable any storage engines you aren't using (especially InnoDB and BSD). Lowering buffers (and possibly the query cache) to acceptable levels for your application may also help, but will be detrimental to performance.

Here is a link to a [MySQL / Apache low memory configuration](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Low_memory_MySQL_/_Apache_configurations), although it references Linux file paths.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 fresh install

Comment: Did removing superfluous storage engines lower the footprint? I'm not familiar with MySQL under Windows, could you update with an abridged my.cnf?